# Outlook indicates the message is in outbox but outbox is empty

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use outlook 2016. All messages I sent are normally stored in the "Sent Items" folder. But I sent a message to several recipients yesterday and it was not copied to the "Sent Items". I am sure the message was sent because I got a reply from one recipient.

When I try to search message in current mailbox then the message is in the search result and it I can see the "Location: Outbox" in the message properties. But the Outbox folder is empty.

Where is the message stored and can I believe it was sent to all of recipients?

I use outlook 2016 and exchange with cached mode.

Answer (score 0):

Tip #1:
In the settings you have an option to keep your replies together with the message you reply to; check whether it is "on".
*(No Outlook available at this time, the location probably also differs between versions)*

Tip #2:
If you can find a message by searching it, the simple method to get it back into e.g. "Inbox" is simply grabbing it and dragging it into the Inbox.

Comment: 1. "Save copies of messages in Sent Items" is on and "When replying save reply in the same folder" is off. 2. The message is resistant to any move attempt. There is no error message but the message is not moved.